# Match a set of numbers to replace with text using jQuery w/Electron/NodeJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron, http-post

What I am trying to do is when I enter in a User ID text field and clicks submit, jQuery/Javascript finds the specific set of numbers and calls a if statement. If one were to match, it'll replace the result with the user name as `User 1` output. If none were to match, then it'll just output as the user ID.

Here's the code.

```
var UserIDField = $("#UserIDField").val(); 
var UserIDSelection = function (UserIDField){
  var UserResult = "";
if (UserIDField === "38123900") {
 UserResult += "User 1";
} else {
 UserResult += "User ID" + UserIDField;
}
```

and then I want the `UserResult` varible to be part of the `form.append` object like this to show up in the RequestBin

```
form.append("Airtable User ID", $(UserIDSelection).val);
```

and did a test request on RequestBin and came out nothing.

[image]

Is there a fix to this?

Comment: You need `()` at the end of `$(UserIDSelection).val` so it's `$(UserIDSelection).val()`

Comment: Got it, but now there's NOTHING in the Value. Will edit the post

Comment: But what are you trying to achieve with the `UserIDSelection function`?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to match a set of 2 numbers (for instance, it's trying to search for a particular number), and if one were to match, the result will change to "User 1", if no match, then it will come out with just the user-input number.

Comment: I'm not sure how the code example is relevant, but it sounds like all you need is the [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UserIDSelection` is expection a parameter, so try with `UserIDSelection(UserIDField)`.

Also i belive you want to return the value of `UserResult` so do `return UserResult`;

**Demo**

```js
var UserIDField = $("#UserIDField").val();
var UserIDSelection = function(UserIDField) {
  var UserResult = "";
  if (UserIDField == "38123900") {
    UserResult += "User 1";
  } else if (UserIDField == "39268955") {
    UserResult += "User 2";
  } else {
    UserResult += "User ID " + $("#UserIDField").val();
  }
  return UserResult;
}

console.log("Airtable User ID", UserIDSelection("125423"));
console.log("Airtable User ID", UserIDSelection("38123900"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="UserIDField" value="38123900" />
```

Comment: Ok, so the `else` part works, however, when I try to input the value `38123900`, it only comes out as `User ID 38123900`. When it matches this specific number, it should be just "User 1" instead of just `User ID 38123900`.

EDIT: I double checked the code, on the first `if` statement, I only put 1 `=` condition, and finally it shows up as "User 1". Thank you!

Comment: So now also, what if it also matches another specific, it changes to "User 2". I tried the `if else` statement, but it came out to only `User 1`.

here's the code `else if (UserIDField = "39268955") { UserResult += "User 2"};`

Comment: @mikey186 I've updated the snippet, but note: using 1x `=` sets the value and using 2x `==` compares the value, so `if (UserIDField = "38123900") {` needs to be `if (UserIDField == "38123900") {`

Comment: I did both `==` but apparently now it's resulting as "User ID 38123900", as if it's pointing to the `else` statement.

Comment: @mikey186 try and run my demo, there you can see it works. Your code code does not work you need to update your question.